# PHP script to remove part of code in many files

Tags: php

A client of us has a site that apparently has been a victim of some sort of malware attack. After a scan we found that many (1000+) files are injected with a piece of PHP code starting on each of these files. I'd like to create a script that automatically removes all these code pieces.

The code that is added starts with:

```
<?php $qwilcq = then a bunch of code

?>
```

Then the normal php code starts. Is there an easy way of creating such a script or is it even possible?

Comment: Yes its easy and yes its possible. However what does the line end with?

Comment: Well basically it's all contained within the first opening and closing PHP tags. For most files after that a PHP opening tag follows and the normal code resumes.

Comment: You are trying to cure the symptom but apparently are not interested in the cause at all...

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I have to deal with this problem and someone else is currently looking into server security in order to see what has caused this. I a combination of solving the problem and preventing it from happening in the future.

Comment: I have Paul, thanks for the information and believe me we are taking this very seriously as this is not the first time we are dealing with such a thing. Maybe I should've asked the question as a general PHP scripting question which would actually give me something to work with.